# "mongoError: Topology was destroyed" when trying to delete/update a document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot from NodeJS that utilizes MongoDB for its database. When I try to delete or update a document, sometimes, it returns `mongoError: Topology was destroyed`. I have read up on this error before and it says that the connection was being interrupted.

Here is the code for my Database Handler:

```js
class DatabaseHandler {
    constructor(client) {
        this.client = client; 
    }

    async connect(callback) {
        try {
            await this.client.connect(); 

            await callback(this.client); 
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err); 
        } finally {
            this.client.close(); 
            console.log("CLIENT CLOSED"); 
        }

    }
}

module.exports = DatabaseHandler;
```

Here is the place that the error occurs:

```js
DB.connect(async (client) => {
    console.log(ObjectId(this._id));
    let DBList = await client.db("Giveaways").collection("giveawayData");
    let delVal = {
        _id: ObjectId(this._id)
    };
    await DBList.deleteOne(delVal); // error occurs here
})
```

I do not think it is because of the `this.client.close()` because it is executed after all of the operations are finished.

Comment: What is the stack trace for the error?

Comment: @Oleg https://pastebin.com/raw/Hz2fcvjr

Comment: The stack trace has insertOne which I do not see anywhere in your question.

Comment: Oops, that was an error from my other piece of code. Here is the one from the deleteOne(): https://pastebin.com/raw/3SxBQEjm

Comment: The error seems to occur most times when I try to modify the database. There is no error with getting data from the database.

Comment: Seems reasonable. If you take just the code in the question and run it, does it succeed?

Comment: It does succeed once I take the code out.

Comment: What are the other operations that are required to produce the failure?

Comment: Are there other operations in other parts of your code that use the same `client` ? It's possible that when you have successfully completed an operation, the `client` will disconnect and subsequent operations will fail.

Comment: @TheeSritabtim If it was in a different Javascript file, then it used another instance of the MongoCleint client. If it was in the same, then it was using the same MongoClient instance.

Comment: Something to take note of, it seems that the error only occurs when I have the Giveaway() Object. If I didn't, then the error never occurs.

Comment: Here is the code for the Giveaway() object: https://pastebin.com/raw/8w7Z7635